# Data passing to a polymer element incomplete

Tags: javascript, polymer

Please excuse the noob question, I've been added to a project using polymer and I can't figure out what I've done incorrectly.

I've got the following component:

```
  <template>
    <div class="hb-graph">
      <h3 class="hb-graph__headline">[[headline]]</h3>
      <div class="hb-graph__container">
        <div class="hb-graph__graph"
             style="width:[[barWidth]]%">
        </div>
        <div class="hb-graph__rates">
          <span class="hb-graph__bar-value">
            [[barValue]]
          </span>
          <span class="hb-graph__bar-value-rate">
            [[barValueRate]]
          </span>
        </div>
        <span class="hb-graph__beginning-range hb-graph__range">
          0
        </span>
        <span class="hb-graph__final-range hb-graph__range">
          [[maxValue]]
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "horizontal-bar-graph",
      properties: {
        headline: String,
        maxValue: String,
        barValue: String,
        barValueRate: String,
        barWidth: Number
      }
    });
  </script>
```

When I load this element into an html template, the only value that appears in the rendered final product is the headline.

```
<horizontal-bar-graph headline="Total Current Flow"
                      maxValue="4000"
                      barValue="3,300"
                      barValueRate="m3/h"
                      barWidth=82.5>
</horizontal-bar-graph>
```

Why wouldn't the other values display at render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#property-name-mapping) you can find the documentation that talks about it.

> Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the dashes. For example, the attribute first-name maps to firstName.

So, this should work:

```
<horizontal-bar-graph headline="Total Current Flow"
                  max-value="4000"
                  bar-value="3,300"
                  bar-value-rate="m3/h"
                  bar-width=82.5>
</horizontal-bar-graph>
```